# Changed data of C++ from QML code

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I begin Qt/QML language. I know that QML can invoke data from C++ code. But is it legal if changing data of C++ from QML source by using Q_INVOKABLE functions (setter functions)? If not, how can I do it. Thanks for your help

Comment: invokables or, preferred, Q_PROPERTY's that have are writable (have a WRITE setter) is the way to go.

Comment: thanks @FrankOsterfeld for quick rep, Is Invokables OK when call  outsite the type(declare a type and call the Q_INVOKABLE function of this type on others)? and about setContextProperty function to register C++ data to QML. can I use the Q_INVOKABLE function to update C++ data from QML code.

Comment: Q_INVOKABLE is okay. You can also put your functions at `public slots:` section but the result is the same. Yes, you can use this. It is meant to be used that way. Sometimes pure QML is not enough and you need to call some functions in C++.